# Why am I getting a debug assertion failed error on running the code

Tags: c, loops, debugging, while-loop

When I enter a password in my program below and press enter I get a debug 
assertion error, specifically isctype.c line 56

Expression:(unsigned)(c+1) <= 256

Could someone help me get around this please?

Code:

```
int main()
{
        int j=0;
        char pass[100];
        int upper=0, lower=0, digit=0, sc=0;

        printf("Enter your password:\n");
        scanf("%s",&pass);

        while(j!=' '){
                if(isalpha(pass[j])){
                        if(isupper(pass[j])){
                                upper++;
                        }
                        else{
                                lower++;
                        }
                }
                else if(isdigit(pass[j])){
                        digit++;
                }
                else{
                        sc++;
                }
                j++;
        }

        if(upper==0||lower==0||digit==0||sc==0){
                printf("Password must contain atleast one upper case, one lower case, one digit and a special character");
        }
        else{
                printf("Good to go");
        }
        return 0;
        _getch();
}
```

Comment: Please do us (and yourself) a favour and indent your code.

Comment: Ok, then if you don't enter any space in your password...loop will go forever (possibly even outside your array)? BTW, _getch() **after** return?

Comment: No space doesn't mean endless loop. OP tests the *counter* variable against `' '` (space character) which is to say `while (j != 32)`, meaning a password smaller causes undefined behavior and a longer one is only partially treated

Comment: You should probably get in the habit of compling your code with -Wall (or the equivalent if not using gcc); doing scanf("%s",&pass) technically works correctly but I'm pretty sure that should trigger a warning and doing scanf("%s",pass); does not.  [specifically:  warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
while (j!=' ')
```

by

```
while (pass[j] != 0)
```

You want to loop as long as `pass[j]` is different from zero. Remember, strings are terminated by a zero.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem in your code is

```
while(j!=' ')
```

which is checking `j` against space (`' '`) which is having [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of 32 (decimal).

Essentially, you're unconditionally *using* `pass` array elements having index 0 to 31.

Then, `pass` is an automatic local variable and you did not initialize it. It contains indeterminate value.

If, your input is less than 31 characters, the remaining element of `pass` will remain uninitialized, and using them further (as the argument to `is....()` family, here) may lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:** You don't need to check for a space, (as `%s` does not accept one). Instead you should check for the null terminator `\0`. Change your code to

1. `scanf("%s",&pass);` to `scanf("%99s",pass);` to avoid possible buffer overflow.
2. `while(j!=' ')` to `while(pass[j])` to loop until the string terminator null.

That said,

- using `_getch()` after *unconditional* `return` statement does not make any sense. You can straight-away remove that `_getch()`.
- The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.